# Ruby on Rails: How to do a query on a table having two foreign key references with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models: Customer, Bank and Account. each customer can have many accounts, so does a bank.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :Accounts

class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :Accounts

Account < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :Customer, :foreign_key => 'customerID'
belongs_to :Bank, :foreign_key => 'bankID'
```

If I want to find all accounts for customer Jack, I can do

```
Customer.find_by_name('jack').Accounts
```

If I want to find all accounts for Citi bank, then I can do query like

```
Bank.find_by_name('Citi').Accounts
```

My question is how can I find the account for Customer Jack which belongs to the Citi bank with ActiveRecord? There is some way to explicitly generate a SQL statement but I wonder how can I do similar queries for other models having the same relationship in a generic way.

Comment: why ruby allows symbols starting with a capital, it looks weird :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
accounts = Account.joins(:bank, :customer)
                  .where( banks: { name: "Citi" }, customers: { name: "Jack" } )
```

I think I've got the plurals bank/banks, customer/customers the right way round.  If it doesn't work first time, try it in the console - build it up by stages, the joins first, then the where bit.

This has the advantage of being only one SQL call.

The rails query guide is very useful - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I did the query with:


`accounts = Account.joins(:bank, :customer).where( :bank_table_name => { :name => "Citi" }, :custom_table_name => { :name => "Jack" } )`

It needs to convert the Model name to actually table name.

Comment: I think you should use plurals in the `joins` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
bank = Bank.find_by_name('City')
accounts = Customer.find_by_name('jack').accounts.where(:bank_id => bank.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, but `where` is a class method instead of a instance method, I think.